# SSH not working from Internet

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

- On Intel® Desktop Board DH55TC
- With Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz
- 500 GB SATA hard drive
- Connected to 42" LG TV with HDMI cable
- TP-Link 300 MB USB wireless LAN
- Wireless keyboard & mouse

I have install ssh server by below code

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw enable
```

Now issue is when I connect from my local IP it connects but when I try to connect from public IP then it **connection refused**. I asked my ISP if they block any ports but they told me no. I am using putty to connect

My internet router configuration
[image]

[image]

What can be issue !!

Comment: Does your ISP give you fixed IP address or are you using a dynamic DNS service?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from somewhere actually outside of the LAN, or are you trying to use your public IP from within the LAN? Not all routers support that (NAT loopback / hairpinning)

Comment: @andrew.46 My ISP gives me fixed IP. I can access my router http page outside my network

Comment: @steeldriver I am connecting my office pc through TeamViewer from my Windows 10 PC and from there I am trying to connect SSH with public IP